# Does Data Normalization affect RMSE & MAE?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, arima, accuracy, mae

Suppose I am using two different methods to perform regression, such as **ARIMA** (1) and a **Neural Network** (2), and I am using the **RMSE** and **MAE** metrics to measure accuracy. For method **(1)**, I do not normalize the data, while for method **(2)** I do.

When I compute the accuracy metrics, will these be scaled differently, due to normalization? If so, do they need to be scaled back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, RMSE and MAE is measured in the same units of your target variable. If the normalisation has effect in your prediction ie Improves/deteriorate this might affect the RMSE and MAE scores but not the way it is scaled. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Great thanks :)